# QEMU: Executing guest program in foreground

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

I use QEMU to run a Windows 10 virtual machine (VM) on an Ubuntu host. My goal is to programmatically instruct the VM to run a specific GUI program in the foreground, as if the user had started the program.

The Windows guest already has the guest agent installed. On the host I can execute

```bash
virsh qemu-agent-command win10_vm "{\"execute\": \"guest-exec\", \"arguments\": { \"path\": \"notepad.exe\", \"arg\": [], \"capture-output\": true}}"
```

and I can see from the task manager that notepad.exe is executed in the background. However, I would have liked the GUI to open.

What I tried so far without success:

- On the Windows guest, run the guest agent service as the user.
- For the qemu-agent-command, change path to execute from `notepad.exe` to `start notepad.exe`, but then the command failed with an error.

Does anyone know how to instruct the VM to run a program in the foreground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(sorry for the repost, I posted previously and got it completely wrong, my mistake)

The reason for this is because by default, the Qemu-GA service runs as the SYSTEM user on session 0, since Windows XP, session 0 is isolated from the UI session for [security reasons](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ba-p/372361)

You can bypass this by using [psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to switch to the user's interactive service.

For step by step instructions, follow:

1. Open services.msc, find the Qemu-GA, and on its Log-on tab, select to run as a specific user, and enable desktop access. Stop, and then start the service.
2. Download and extract psexec to C:\psexec.exe (or any other path of your choosing)
3. You can now use the following command to launch UI as the user.

`qm guest exec 100 -- C:\\psexec.exe -accepteula -i 1 notepad.exe` (for proxmox)

`virsh -c qemu:///system qemu-agent-command win10_vm "{\"execute\": \"guest-exec\", \"arguments\": { \"path\": \"C:\\\\Users\\\\matt\\\\Downloads\\\\PSTools\\\\PsExec.exe\", \"arg\": [\"-accepteula\", \"-i\", \"1\", \"notepad.exe\"], \"capture-output\": true}}"` (for libvirt)

Comment: Thanks! Your instructions put me on track. I needed two more modifications:
1) psexec failed with an access error until I disabled the firewall on the guest (not ideal, but the VM runs for a few minutes only).
2) Had to modify the command to `virsh -c qemu:///system qemu-agent-command win10_vm "{\"execute\": \"guest-exec\", \"arguments\": { \"path\": \"C:\\\\Users\\\\matt\\\\Downloads\\\\PSTools\\\\PsExec.exe\", \"arg\": [\"-accepteula\", \"-i\", \"1\", \"notepad.exe\"], \"capture-output\": true}}"`